# Remove existing items in listbox from database

Tags: c#, sql, listbox

I am trying to delete the items within the listbox, which already exists in my database. My listbox is populated by a set of random names, and the ones that are equal to the data from the table rows should be deleted.
My code:

```
        SqlCommand RemoveUserName = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Name WHERE ([Name] = @check)", Con);
        RemoveUserName.Parameters.AddWithValue("@check", listbox1.Items);
        SqlDataReader dr = RemoveUserName.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Remove(); // ?? Remove the names which are already in the database

        }
        else
        {
          // remain in listbox
        }
```

Getting an error in my parameter value and I don't know how to delete the said items.

EDITED my current code:

```
    SqlCommand RemoveUserName = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Name", Con);
    SqlDataReader dr = RemoveUserName.ExecuteReader();
        while (!dr.Read())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; ++i)
            {
                if (listBox1.Items[i].ToString() == dr["Name"].ToString())
                    listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.Items[i]);
            }
        }
```

Has no error anymore, but is still not functional.

WORKING CODE:

```
          for (int i = listBox1.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [Name] SET [Name] = Name WHERE [Name] = @name", Con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", listBox1.Items[i].ToString());
                if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i);
                }
          }
        }
```

Thanks @ LarsTech

Comment: Getting and error in what parameter value?

Comment: In the listbox1.Items value

Comment: The method .Remove expects an object.  You need to pass in the value that you want to remove in the method.  I'm not sure I'm following you here honestly but the code should look something like ```listBox1.Items.Remove(item);``` where item is the value for whatever you're removing.

Comment: I'm basically trying to delete the values in the listbox, which has a similar data from the table row data in my SQL database

Comment: I'm getting an error on this part: SqlDataReader dr = checkUserName.ExecuteReader(); which says: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll Additional information: No mapping exists from object type System.Windows.Forms.ListBox+ObjectCollection to a known managed provider native type.

Comment: Put the error message [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48751268/edit). Do not try to describe errors in comments; people don't read them and you can't format code in comment boxes.

Comment: I updated my post, has no error anymore. But is still not functional

Comment: RemoveUserName is a SELECT statement?  You need a DELETE statement.  If you are only removing one entry, you don't have to loop through the list.

Comment: I'm not trying to delete the whole data in my SQL table though, I'm only trying to delete the Listbox data, which has an existing data already from the row.

Comment: @D.Trump123 the solution you posted is not very optimal. Imagine you have 100 items in listbox, you are then opening 100 db connections for doing no actual db transaction. You could do this in just 1 db call. Or maybe you are not opening 100 connections, but DB involvement in loop is unnecessary. Try to consider all before final implementation. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

It helps to loop backwards through the list in order to avoid indexing issues:

```
for (int i = listBox1.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
  using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM [Name] WHERE [Name] = @name", Con)) {
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", listBox1.Items[i].ToString());
    if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0) {
      listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i);
    }
  }
}
```

ExecuteNonQuery will return the number of records affected, so if it's greater than zero, the name was found and deleted.

Make sure to close your connection object, too.  Best by putting it also in a using block the way the SqlCommand object is in my example.

Your table and column names need to be improved.

Comment: Hi, Thanks your code worked. But, is there a way to not delete the entire data from the Database. As I only want the listbox data to get removed.

Comment: @D.Trump123 The code only deletes the names in the list box.

Comment: Yes it deletes it in the listbox, but it also deletes the entire row in the database. The DELETE FROM statement completely erases the row data.

Comment: @D.Trump123 I don't know enough about your database structure, but boy, does that sound odd.  I guess you want an UPDATE query instead?  "UPDATE [Name] SET [Name]='' WHERE [Name]=@name"

Comment: I keep getting the error: Incorrect syntax near WHERE

Answer (score 0):

As I understood,

1) You need to delete items from listbox that already exists in your database and read by SqlDataReader.

You first need to loop into reader. So instead of !`while(reader.Read())` use `while(reader.Read())`

2) Now you want to remove actual item from listbox, if it exists in reader.

So try to do following to remove item from `listbox` inside `reader` `while` loop

```
for (int n = listBox.Items.Count - 1; n >= 0; --n)
  {
    var removelistitem = dr["Name"].ToString();
    if (listBox.Items[n].ToString().Contains(removelistitem))
      {
        listBox.Items.RemoveAt(n);
      }
  }
```

Now after `while` loop execution. your listbox will only have items not present in your reader (data from database).

Hope this helps.

**Edit**

Its ok to loop in listbox items.

Use RemoveAt instead. (See above answer)

Comment: It has an error of ListBox.ObjectCollection does not contain a definition for 'FindByText'

Comment: Oh. Misunderstood with with other Items object. Wait for edited answer. @D.Trump123

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
    while (!dr.Read())
    {
        for (int i=0; i<listBox1.Items.Count; ++i)
        {
            if (listBox1.Items[i].ToString() == dr["columnName"].ToString())
                listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.Items[i]);
        }
    }
```

`SqlReader` must be read before use it. If there's no rows in the Reader, code in `while` block won't be executed.

**EDIT** I got a problem making you unhappy....

The code you provided:

```
RemoveUserName.Parameters.AddWithValue("@check", listbox1.Items);
```

Is wrong, because `@check` parameter expects `string`, but you provided was `ObjectCollection`. Revise query `"SELECT * FROM Name WHERE ([Name] = @check)"` to `"SELECT * FROM Name"`. and remove the line `AddWithValue`.

Comment: Getting this error, ListBox.ObjectCollection does not contain a definition for 'ToArray' and no extension method 'ToArray' accepting a first argument of type 'ListBox.ObjectCollection' could be found (are you missing a directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @D.Trump123 Revised answer, try again.

Comment: Still getting an error in this part: 
 SqlDataReader dr = checkUserName.ExecuteReader();

which says: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll 

Additional information: No mapping exists from object type System.Windows.Forms.ListBox+ObjectCollection to a known managed provider native type.

Comment: @D.Trump123 I can't see the declaration of checkUserName, but RemoveUserName. Did you check name of variables correctly?

Comment: Oh my bad, I corrected it. Yet, it still shows the error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll Additional information: No mapping exists from object type System.Windows.Forms.ListBox+ObjectCollection to a known managed provider native type. Still, from the same line:   RemoveUserName.Parameters.AddWithValue("@check", listbox1.Items); Even after I corrected the names

Comment: I guess the datareader dr can't execute the parameter I've added "RemoveUserName.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", listBox1.Items);"

Comment: @D.Trump123 That's correct. I revised answer. see it why you were struggled.

Comment: I noticed that too, but I couldn't find a datareader which reads an ObjectCollection. There is no error now, but the function still won't delete the existing fields in the listbox.

Comment: Edited my post, kindly check the current code I'm using. Thanks. Still not functional though.